# Fail to open kibana homepage from development environment

Tags: kibana, development-environment

I'm setup kibana local development by following up the wiki from

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/7.1/CONTRIBUTING.md#setting-up-your-development-environment

```
yarn es snapshot
```

i'm able to run elastichsearch locally at http://localhost:9200/ with above cli.

```
yarn start
```

i'm able to start the server for kibana with above cli, and according to log, it promote me to open http://localhost:5601/ykl,

```
server    log   [15:57:39.991] [info][listening] Server running at http://localhost:5603/ykl
server    log   [15:57:40.150] [info][status][plugin:spaces@8.0.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
```

after i logined with default user/password, it return back a error response.

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}
```

I'm not able to access page 
http://localhost:5601/ykl/app/kibana#/management,
it will redirect me to http://localhost:5601/ykl/#/management with error response just as above error json response.

My question is what's wrong with the default user account to access homepage? how to change kibana configuration to allow me to access homepage.

ps:
I'm able to open status page without any problem http://localhost:5601/ykl/status#?_g=()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer myself.
just use another default user account which has permission, actually, i login with `elastic` and it works

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.1/built-in-users.html